# Display Table-Cell: Remove Right and Left Border Space?

Tags: css

I'd like to display four elements side by side. I'm using `display: table` and `display: table-cell` to accomplish this:

```css
#container {
  width: 960px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 400px;
  }

#table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  }

div.item {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="table">
    <div class="item">
      Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Text 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Text 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Text 4
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

How can I make the rightmost and leftmost cells flush with the container `div's` edge and maintain equal spacing between the inner cells?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way would be to use `border` on cells instead of `border-spacing`. Then you could cancel out `border` on the first of last cell. Also, keep the colour same as that of your container.

```
div.item {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 10px solid orange; /* Same colour as of the container */
  border-left: none;         /* reset left border to keep uniform */
}
div.item:last-child { border-right: none; } /* remove from last one */
```

**Example Snippet**:

```css
#container {
  width: 960px;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 400px;
  }

#table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  }

div.item {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: blue;
  border: 10px solid orange;
  border-left: none;
}
div.item:last-child { border-right: none; }
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div id="table">
    <div class="item">
      Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Text 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Text 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      Text 4
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well. I didn't represent in my example that I have 100% width images in each cell. When I remove the border from the last element, it stretches the image a bit. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Comment: You can make the right border of the last div of the same colour of the div i.e. blue.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the table div and make container display: flex with space-between justification.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 4
    </div>
</div>

#container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.item {
    background-color: red;
    width: 24%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kyy7qgLz/2/