# Four Columns Equal Width, 0 Outer Margin, Equal Inner Margin

Tags: html, css

This is a spin off [Display Table-Cell: Remove Right and Left Border Space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786138/display-table-cell-remove-right-and-left-border-space).

I was trying to create a solution using divs and inner margins of equal width but I get unwanted spacing in between causing my last div to wrap.

https://jsfiddle.net/kyy7qgLz/1/

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#container {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
.item {
    margin-left: 4%;
    width: 22%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: red;
}
.item:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0%;
}

<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Where is the extra spacing coming from and how do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cleanest solution here is to use flexbox. When you use `display: inline-block` you are saying “render these elements as blocks of text” so the browser correctly shows the white space you included between your HTML elements.

If you instead set `display: flex` on your container you will have more accurately described the layout you intend. Namely, you will have said direct children of this container should use a flex layout (instead of a layout intended for text).

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
#container {
    background-color: blue;
    display: flex;
}
.item {
    margin-left: 4%;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}
.item:first-of-type {
    margin-left: 0%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        Text 1
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 2
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 3
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        Text 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did the trick.  I even cleaned it up a little more using flex justify-content.  https://jsfiddle.net/kyy7qgLz/2/

Comment: Nice work! Missed that you were asking for equal width margins.

Answer (score 3):

You need to comment (or removE) the space (or new line) between your HTML elements when you want inline-block elements to not be espaced :

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">
        Text 1
    </div><!--
    --><div class="item">
        Text 2
    </div><!--
    --><div class="item">
        Text 3
    </div><!--
    --><div class="item">
        Text 4
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Or use `div#container{font-size:0}`. I'm a firm believer in clean code, so this ends up being the cleanest solution :)

Comment: Since css is for styling, I don't think this is a `clean` solution. But that's my opinion. If you don't want space between your elements, remove them, don't make them appear as 0. I said in my answer "(or remove)" which is what I usually do.

Comment: Eh pohtato pohtahto. I could argue that spacing is a styling element. I think having a single line in my css file instead of a bunch of `<!-- -->` in my HTML is prettier to look at, but that's my opinion.

Comment: Pretty and clean are not the same things.

Comment: True, but they are analogous, especially when it comes to HTML.

Comment: Agree with @dievardump. Using `font-sze: 0` to solve this problem is not clean. You will confuse the hell out of anyone new to CSS.

Comment: put all of this in a build process and you have no 'ugly' issues to deal with.

Comment: Both removing/commenting whitespace and font-size:0 work.  Using font-size:0 on the container forces font-size required on the item which does get hard to follow for future code supporters.  But I'm also nit-picky about my html and removing whitespace looks ugly too.  Is there another method to do this without a workaround?

Comment: and usually there's only 1 element with a specific id, no need to do `div#...`

Comment: @AdamMilecki 'view-source' HTML is not something we should be concerned about. Use a build tool like gulp and remove the spaces between elements you require there. That way the code you edit is clean, and the end result is also clean.